# XCode 4.0.2 and warnings not going away!

Tags: xcode4, warnings, semantics

I upgraded from xcode 4.0 to 4.0.2 today (not sure why, but everything i read pretty much says that "i have to"... why is this?).

Anyway, after this upgrade I noticed a warning due to "static" (class) method call. I have a class that has 2 methods with the same name (one method has an extra parameter, so the signatures are slightly different). This wasnt an issue before, but now im getting a semantic warning. The warning only complains about one of these method calls.

In desperation i replaced all warning lines with the other method signature. The warning still shows up.

So again, in desperation, I commented out all the lines causing warnings. But the warnings still show up. I even restarted XCode and even rebooted the machine, but no progress.
Each time i test this i am cleaning and rebuilding.

Is this an XCode 4.0.2 bug or am i totally missing some new XCode 4.0 concept here???

*** Updated ***

It appears this was a user error on my part. I have 2 build targets. All the warnings were coming from the non-selected Target. Once I selected the proper target and clean+built again, all warnings disappeared. - RESOLVED.

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste the exact warnings you’re getting, and the corresponding source code?

Comment: Also, this whole time my XCode is downloading various libraries (iOS, developer library...). Not sure if this is the reason why.

Comment: The warning says that +BeginViewAnimations: **animation** Duration: was not found. The code you’ve pasted uses +BeginViewAnimations: **animate** Duration:.

Comment: The code i pasted comments out BeginViewAnimation. So why would the warning complain about it???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are neither defining the Method +BeginViewAnimation:animationDuration: nor calling, so it looks ok. Obviously XCode sees the call at some other place. Or maybe all that is needed is to clean target? This cures a lot of issues.

**EDIT**

By removing the code from the question one cannot see the context anymore, yet the comment below proves that my analysis was right: XCode has seen the call at the other target, properly cleaning, selecting and building the targets has cured the problem.

Comment: As i've stated, im always cleaning and rebuilding.

Comment: Also, i am defining BeginViewAnimations. It is in the .h file.